# Can creatures outside of Crystal Spheres dream?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, dnd-3.5e, planes, conversion, spelljammer

Assumptions: all material from spelljammer, 3.0, 3.5, web/dragon and Pathfinder are available. Everything in this campaign setting is being converted to Pathfinder. All available separate campaign settings are their own crystal spheres. I try to remove as much DM fiat as I can, but some is required to do conversions and a lot is required to implement spelljammer, which this question is based around.

This section will be updated based on clarification request. Please comment to suggest clarifications.

Problem: Inter-planar travel is not possible outside of a crystal sphere. The dimension of dreams / region of dreams exist as kinda sort of part of the ethereal plane. If you can dream, you go to those places as a mental projection and play around in your dream demiplane. Some crystal spheres have more danger here than others depending on local creatures.

If you're outside of the spheres however Inter-planar spells and abilities don't work. Can you still enter the Dream world via sleeping? If the answer is yes, can you do so with spells/powers/abilities? Are there Night Hags prowling the spaces between spheres through the dreams of creatures traveling in the phlogiston?

Comment: I started with Spelljammer just because this question centers around that campaign setting. Planar experts would be ideal, especially those who have experience with Spelljammer as well.

Comment: I removed 3e so that planes could be added as it's more important to the question.

Comment: I think this looks good. Maybe others will suggest to narrow down the focus and ask for two separate questions. If that happens, then don't feel disheartened - it is normal procedure :)

Comment: The Planescape campaign setting clarified a great deal about the connections between planes. I don't have time to pour through the Planescape books right now, but perhaps someone else with more time could dig something up?

Comment: From what I can find in a brief googling, planescape doesn't mention Spelljammer much? The problem is the phlogiston outside the crystal spheres, where planar travel functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Up to the DM

I apologize in advance as I will provide an answer from a mix of editions in spite of the dnd-3.5e tag, as the question is also tagged Spelljammer and it is about conversion.

There are actually two subquestions here:

1. Can you dream without access to a plane of dreams?
2. Is it possible to access the plane of dreams from the phlogiston?

The answer to neither of these questions is well-established within the default D&D Great Wheel Cosmology.

Regarding the first question, the 3e *Manual of Planes* seems to give a concrete answer: it defines a Region of Dreams, which dreamers visit every time they fall asleep, whether they will it or not. Unfortunately, the Region of Dreams is described in an appendix on "Variant Planes & Cosmologies" and it is left outside of the Great Wheel cosmology. Whether or not this plane is included in the campaign (and whether dimensional barriers can block the trip) is thus left to the DM.

Regarding the second question: As far at the 2e *A Guide to the Ethereal Plane* (AGttEP) goes, the dream plane is located behind the Veil of Sleep, which is itself located between the Border and the Deep ethereal (page 54). Yet whether or not the Bother ethereal touches the phlogiston is left uncertain in AGttEP (page 7). For an answer to that, we could turn to the Spelljammer boxed set. According to the *Concordance of Arcane Space* sourcebook, the access to other planes is not possible from the phlogiston (page 18) in the absence of very strong magic.

Finally, before making a decision, I suggest reading the Pathfinder SRD's [description](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-rules/esoteric-planes/#Dimension_of_Dreams) of the "Dimension of Dreams". This dimension described to be in the Ethereal Plane, yet it is not accessible with spells like Planeshift. When a mortal dreams, its soul creates a dream avatar known as a lucid body. Ethereal Plane appears to play a more prominent role in Pathfinder, so a GM might prefer access to parts of it in the phlogiston.